# Autofill column until last column using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to autofill my formula to the last column. Here is my code:

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:" & LastColumn & "1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I have succeeded in counting the last column by variable `LastColumn`, but during the autofill, it failed. So I want to autofill starting from column B to the column `Lastcolumn`.

Please help. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: thanks!! it works!!

Answer (score 2):

You have a number in `LastColumn`, so you can't use it directly in `Range`. Use this instead:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, LastColumn)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```